# Determine whether the matrices will form a vector space over R under the operations of matrix addition and scalar multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am new to Linear Algebra and I encountered this question to determine whether the matrices of the form
$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
* & * & 1 \\
* & 1 & * \\
1 & * & * \\
\end{matrix}
\right]
$
and
$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & * \\
0 & * & 0 \\
* & 0 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}
\right]
$
where $*$ represents an arbitrary real number, form a vector space over R under the usual
operations of matrix addition and scalar multiplication.

To check that these matrices form a real space or not we have to check whether the axioms of forming a vector space are satisfied or not, but for the matrix of first form I am not sure whether the axiom of additive identity satisfied or not since the additive identity doesn't exist in this situation or am I wrong

I am struck in this confusion , please clarify my doubt

Comment: the existence of the identity is an axiom for the vector spaces, so...

Comment: You don't even need to go that far. If $M$ is a matrix of the first type $M+M$ or $2M$ are not of that type, so they can't form a space.

Comment: @loop You are correct in saying that the first set does not contain an additive identity, and therefore fails to be a vector space.